# jQuery jqplot - How to create multi line of a label

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqplot

I'm having a lengthier label that hits near by labels in my jqplot in xaxis.
I tried with *angle* but still it looks uglier because of that single label alone looks lengthy others are shorter. 
I used

```
<br/>
```

tag in between that label but it shows exactly what I typed in the screen also. Here is my config for jqplot.

```
seriesDefaults: {
                    renderer:jQuery.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                    pointLabels: { show: true, location: 'e', edgeTolerance: -15 },
                    shadowAngle: 135,
                    rendererOptions: {
                        varyBarColor: true,
                        smooth: true,
                        animation: {
                            show: true
                        },
                        barWidth: 30
                    }
                },
axes:{
                        yaxis: {
                            label:'No. of candidates',
                            fontSize: '10pt',
                            labelRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisLabelRenderer,

                    },
                    xaxis:{
                        renderer: jQuery.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                        ticks: ['ABC Offers','XXX Offers','XXX Joinees','No show/Offer Declined/<br/>Revoked/Terminated','Yet to Join'],
                        tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
                        tickOptions: {
                          angle: -20,
                          fontSize: '10pt'
                        }
                    }
               }
```

Give some if you experienced it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. When we use the jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer it doest support HTML tags.
If you **remove** the below line from xaxis it will split the line.

```
tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer ,
```

But the problem is, if you want to Rotate axis tick labels or slanting the label by angle, those options wont work.